# JavaScript dynamically element duplicate each time function is called

Tags: javascript

I have a function called validateForm() which checks for me form input. If the input is not as it should be (each field filled) alert message should appear and should be removed after 3 seconds and it does, but each time I call this function this element is created in DOM. How can I improve that code? What I want to get is div with alert message as below, but not created in the DOM each time the function is called, but once.

```
static validateForm() {
    const title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
    const author = document.querySelector('#author').value;
    const isbn = document.querySelector('#isbn').value;

    if (title === '' || author === '' || isbn === '') {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'alert alert-dismissible alert-danger';
        const message = document.createTextNode('Please fill all fields before adding.');
        div.appendChild(message);

        const bookForm = document.querySelector('#book-form');
        bookForm.parentNode.insertBefore(div, bookForm);


        setTimeout(() => {
            div.classList.add('d-none');
        }, 3000);

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: since you use `applenChild`, the related action is `removeChild`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//construct div globally
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'alert alert-dismissible alert-danger';
div.style.display = "none";
const bookForm = document.querySelector('#book-form');
bookForm.parentNode.insertBefore(div, bookForm);


static validateForm() {
    const title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
    const author = document.querySelector('#author').value;
    const isbn = document.querySelector('#isbn').value;

    if (title === '' || author === '' || isbn === '') {
        const message = document.createTextNode('Please fill all fields before adding.');
        div.html = message;
        div.style.display = "block";

        setTimeout(() => {
            div.classList.add('d-none');
        }, 3000);

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create div for alert in your HTML and give it class **hidden** to hide it.

Then when the input is not as it should be, you can change the inner HTML for that div element by your alert message and add class **show** for it to display it.

When the show time is over let's remove class **show** from that div.

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
} 

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the inversion of `appendChild` is `removeChild`, in case you do not want to toggle the style

---

```js
//you can reuse the div
const div = document.createElement('div');
{
  div.className = 'alert alert-dismissible alert-danger';
  const message = document.createTextNode('Please fill all fields before adding.');
  div.appendChild(message);
}
function foo() {
  const bookForm = document.querySelector('#root');
  bookForm.parentNode.insertBefore(div, bookForm);

  setTimeout(()=>bookForm.parentNode.removeChild(div), 3000);
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<button onclick="foo()">show node</button>
```

Comment: One thing to be aware of if you go this route, storing it in a global var and removing the node from the DOM (as opposed to just hiding it; or creating the div in `foo` so it is local) is that if `foo` is clicked more than once in a 3 second window, it will create 2 timers, when the second timer fires it will raise an error because it tries to `removeChild` but the node was already removed by the first timer. No one would probably notice so long as they aren't viewing your site with the dev console. So, it probably isn't a big deal, but still something to be aware of.

Comment: You could use [`Node.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) inside of the `setTimeout` callback to see if the div is currently in the DOM before trying to remove it, which would prevent any errors: `setTimeout(()=> { let parent = bookForm.parentNode; if (parent.contains(div)) { parent.removeChild(div); } }, 3000);`

Comment: @UselessCode If it is clicked more than once, it may be preferred to extend the visible time (which is a little more complex). I'd keep my answer as-is, but thanks for the great suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to create the div using html with the class **d-none** and then add the class **d-block** whenever you want to display the div. or use JQuery slideDown() function. Then set a timeout and remove the **d-block** class and add **d-none** class or use JQuery slideUp() function